# Spring boot JPA: getReferenceById returns an hibernate proxy instead of EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit5

I cannot find a solution to my issue wth a JUnit test.

The database is initialized with two lines in a table (H2 database). The aim of the JUnit test is to check that we have an exception when we search a line with a unknown id.

In my service I have something like that:

```
private MyEntity getMyEntityById(final String id) throws MyBusinessException {
    try {
        MyEntity entity = this.myEntityRepository.getReferenceById(id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new MyBusinessException(BusinessError.UNKNOWN_ID_CODE);
        }
    }
    catch (final EntityNotFoundException e) {
        throw new MyBusinessException(BusinessError.UNKNOWN_ID_CODE, e);
    }
}
```

In the test I expect to have MyBusinessException with BusinessError.UNKNOWN_ID_CODE because in the service I expect to have an EntityNotFoundException because the javadoc of `getReferenceById()` method says that:
"Depending on how the JPA persistence provider is implemented this is very likely to always return an instance and throw an javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException on first access.".

At least, I expect to have null as return.

Instead of that, I have an hibernate proxy returned and the test is in failure.

I do not understand how to have what I expect. Can you help me to understand please?

Comment: `getReferernceById` will always return a proxy, instead use `findById`.

Comment: Oh yes ok thank you. Previsously it was `getOne` that was used and it was replaced by `getReferernceById` following javadoc because it was deprecated. But it is not what we wanted following the code. And do you know why the javadoc talks about EntityNotFoundException if not found?

Comment: That will only be thrown if you start using the proxy by caling methods, it will then go to the database to fetch the entity, and that is the point it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to run it is to use transaction for your test

For example

```java
@Test
@Transactional
void testSomething() {
   //logic    
}
```